# How can I use a preprocessor macro in an #import directive?

Tags: c-preprocessor

Our company's main project has several preprocessor constants that must be adjusted for different customers. When the program was first written, it was considered enough to merely to build Debug and Release versions of the code. It never occurred to anyone until I got tired of rebuilding the project all the time that we could use preprocessor constants and project settings to build into different folders for each customer.

But we have one ActiveX DLL our project needs that has to be in a specific folder. (Making that an ActiveX DLL was yet another in the long list of bad decisions my company made on this project.) That DLL is #imported into the code using this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #import "..\Debug\CapsHelper.dll" no_namespace
#else
    #import "..\Release\CapsHelper.dll" no_namespace
#endif
```

I am currently trying to build for a customer named Algoma. So, I want to create a preprocessor constant named CUSTOMER that would contain "Alcoma" and then tell the compiler to import from a folder named either "Debug Alcoma" or "Release Alcoma". How would I do that?

I tried this:

```
#define CUSTOMER Alcoma
#ifdef _DEBUG
#import "..\Debug " #CUSTOMER "\CapsHelper.dll" no_namespace
#else
    #import "..\Release " #CUSTOMER "\CapsHelper.dll" no_namespace
#endif
```

But that didn't work. It didn't work without the # before CUSTOMER either.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using MSVC, and I haven't tested this solution with it. But it should work:

```
#define XSTR(X) #X
#define STR(X)  XSTR(X)

#ifdef _DEBUG
#import STR(..\Debug CUSTOMER\CapsHelper.dll) no_namespace
#else
#import STR(..\Release CUSTOMER\CapsHelper.dll) no_namespace
#endif
```

The basic issue with your attempt (aside from the fact in standard C/C++, `#` can only occur inside a macro expansion) is that while `#include` (and, I suppose, `#import`) will macro-expand their argument, they will not perform string concatenation. So the stringify operator needs to be applied to the entire string.